# question about shell script. unable to getting this question

Tags: linux, shell-script

devise a script that takes a filename as argument (which must exist in current directory) and locates from your home directory tree all pathnames of its links. The list should be mailed to self.
I have tried this, but I dont know what exactly script wants..

```
#!/bin/bash
echo. "enter file name"
read name
if [ $name == "a1.txt" ]; then
source a1.txt
fi 
/* a1.txt file contents tree -l */
```

Comment: Why do you have to enter the file name, if `a1.txt` is the only name allowed? And did you look at `man find` if you want to locate files in a directory tree? I'm afraid I don't understand what exactly you expect the script to do.

Comment: This is looks very much like homework. We don't do that here.

Comment: Hint: Try `man [` and the `-f` bit. And another hint: `if [ -f "$1" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's break this down into bits:

1. Take a filename as an argument
2. Make sure that the file exists (and is a regular file)
3. Find all (symbolic) links to the file under `$HOME`
4. Mail this list of files to `$LOGUSER`

A script may take an argument (or several).  The command line arguments are available in the *positional parameters* `$1`, `$2` etc.  Since we only will get one argument, we're only concerned with what's in `$1`.

```
name="$1"
```

To test whether a name exists, we may use

```
if [ -e "$name" ]; then ... fi
```

In this case, we're interested in testing whether a name does *not* exist:

```
if [ ! -e "$name" ]; then
   echo 'Name does not exist in directory' >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Since we're outputting a *diagnostic message* (an error message in this case), we're doing so to the *standard error stream* by redirecting the output from `echo` with `>&2`. We also terminate the script with a non-zero exit status to signal that something went wrong.

If we want to make sure that the file not only exists, but also that it's a *regular file*, i.e. not a directory or a device node or something else, change `-e` to `-f` (read the `test` manual).

To find all symbolic links in our home directory, we may use

```
find "$HOME" -type l
```

With either of `bash` or `ksh93` we may look at these files and compare them with the file we've been given by the user using

```
if [[ "$name" -ef "$link" ]]; then ... fi
```

where `$name` would be `$1` and `$link` would be the name of the symbolic link returned from `find`.  The `-ef` operator will return a true value if the two operands refer to the same file (after resolving all symbolic links).

One may combine the `find` with the above test like this:

```
find "$HOME" -type l |
while read -r link; do
    if [[ "$name" -ef "$link" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$link"
    fi
done
```

To send an email, use the `mail` command.  This may be tagged on to the end of the previous pipeline:

```
find "$HOME" -type l |
while read -r link; do
    if [[ "$name" -ef "$link" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$link"
    fi
done |
mail -s "These are the links" "$LOGUSER@localhost"
```

`$LOGUSER` will hold your username.  Use `"$(id -un)"` if `$LOGUSER` for some reason is not set properly, or just replace the whole string with whatever email address you'd like to use.

Comment: bt after executions it said
@ localhost ...user address required
and email saved to dead.letter

Comment: @AvinashUtekar Well, you may use whatever email address you wish there.

Comment: i wrote like this 
..

mail -s "These are the links" "Avi@localhost"
but it sends to dead.letter

Comment: @AvinashUtekar Use a valid email address, one that you know works. If that doesn't work, make sure your system has an MTA ("mail transfer agent")  installed, like `postfix` or `exim` or similar. If that's a problem, please submit that as a new question.